# If f(n) is Omega(g(n)) then 2^(f(n)) is Omega(2^g(n)). Is this true or false

Tags: algorithm, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

For this question, I thought it's true because I thought the question is basically asking `f(n)` is greater than or equal to `g(n)` then is `2^(f(n))` greater than or equal to `2^(g(n))`

So if we take an instance of `f(n) = 2n` and `g(n) = n`, `f(n)` is `> g(n)`. Then `2^2n` is greater than `2^n`.

But my friend said that's not correct, can someone give me some insight? I think I might have some misunderstanding of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You're interested in proving or disproving this claim:

> If f(n) = Ω(g(n)), then 2<sup>f(n)</sup> = Ω(2<sup>g(n)</sup>).

When you see a statement like this, it's often helpful to clarify what f and g are here. Specifically, the statement above really means the following:

> **For any functions f and g**, if f(n) = Ω(g(n)), then 2<sup>f(n)</sup> = Ω(2<sup>g(n)</sup>)

So in this sense, if you want to prove that this statement is true, you'd need to approach it by showing that this statement is true *for any possible choice of f and g*, not just by picking a single f and a single function g and confirming that the relationship holds for those particular functions. In this sense, your friend is correct.

(On the other hand, if you want to *disprove* this claim, you just need to give examples of functions f and g where f(n) = Ω(g(n)) but 2<sup>f(n)</sup> ≠ Ω(2<sup>g(n)</sup>).)

As a hint for this question: asymptotic notations like O, Ω, and Θ all completely ignore constant factors. If f(n) = Ω(g(n)), then you can scale either f or g by any constant factor that you'd like and the relationship will still hold. On the other hand, constant factors in an exponent radically change the properties of that exponent. for example, the function e<sup>n</sup> grows exponentially slower than the function e<sup>2n</sup>, since e<sup>2n</sup> = (e<sup>2</sup>)<sup>n</sup>, which is an exponential function with a higher base. In other words, you can't scale exponents by a constant factor without completely changing their rates of growth.

Based on this disconnect - that Ω notation can't tell apart functions that differ by a constant factor, but that exponential functions are very sensitive to constant factors - do you think this statement is true or false? Based on the advice above, how would you prove a statement like that?

Answer (score 1):

> For this question, I thought it's true because I thought the question is basically asking `f(n)` is greater than or equal to `g(n)` then is `2^(f(n))` greater than or equal to `2^(g(n))`

Nope. That's not what big-omega notation means at all. `f(n) = Ω(g(n))` means that for sufficiently large `n`, the ratio `f(n)/g(n)` is bounded below by a positive constant.

To see that `f(n) = Ω(g(n))` does not imply `2^f(n) = Ω(2^g(n))`, consider `f(n) = n - log(n)` and `g(n) = n`. Then `2^f(n) = (2^n)/n` and `2^g(n) = 2^n`, and `2^f(n) != Ω(2^g(n))`.

Comment: Yes. Can you also answer the title question, then?

Comment: @Bergi: I think the answer is fine just pointing out the questioner's misunderstanding, but sure, counterexample added.

Comment: Oh, good one, I had naively assumed the implication to still be correct.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, the statement is true.

We can find constants that work by the definition of big Omega. Specifically, let C_2 = 2^C_1 and let n >= max(n_1, n_2).

[Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvKP5.png)